# How to Concatenate Mixed Types (int, char, ...) Into a Char string?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

This is what I have, it works, but I want to get rid of Strings to save space and prevent the well known String problems that crash programs and cause strangeness.

```
String timeString;                              //Build date time data 21 chars + null

void GetRTCTime(){                               //Routine read real time clock, format data
  byte second;byte minute;byte hour;byte DoW;byte Date;byte month;byte year;
  Wire.beginTransmission(DS1307);                //Open I2C to RTC DS1307
  Wire.write(0x00);                              //Write reg pointer to 0x00 Hex
  Wire.endTransmission();                        //End xmit to I2C.  Send requested data.
  Wire.requestFrom(DS1307, 7);                   //Get 7 bytes from RTC buffer
  second = BCD2DEC(Wire.read() & 0x7f);          //Seconds.  Remove hi order bit
  minute = BCD2DEC(Wire.read());                 //Minutes
  hour = BCD2DEC(Wire.read() & 0x3f);            //Hour.  Remove 2 hi order bits
  DoW = BCD2DEC(Wire.read());                    //Day of week
  Date = BCD2DEC(Wire.read());                   //Date
  month = BCD2DEC(Wire.read());                  //Month
  year = BCD2DEC(Wire.read());                   //Year
  timeString = 2000+year;                        //Build Date-Time data to write to SD
  if (month<10){timeString = timeString + '0';}  //Pad leading 0 if needed
  timeString = timeString + month;               //Month (1-12)  
  if(Date<10){timeString = timeString + '0';}    //Pad leading 0 if needed
  timeString = timeString + Date;                //Date (1-30)
  timeString = timeString + DoWList[DoW];        //1Sun-7Sat (0=null)
  if (hour<10){timeString = timeString + '0';}   //Pad leading 0 if needed
  timeString = timeString + hour + ':';          //HH (0-24)
  if (minute<10){timeString = timeString + '0';} //Pad leading 0 if needed
  timeString = timeString + minute + ':';        //MM (0-60)
  if (second<10){timeString = timeString + '0';} //Pad leading 0 if needed
  timeString = timeString + second;              //SS (0-60)
}
```

What I want is something like this (yes, I know it's wrong) using a fixed length buffer of characters:

```
char timeString[22];                            //Build date time data 21 chars + null

void GetRTCTime(){                               //Routine read real time clock, format data
  byte second;byte minute;byte hour;byte DoW;byte Date;byte month;byte year;
  Wire.beginTransmission(DS1307);                //Open I2C to RTC DS1307
  Wire.write(0x00);                              //Write reg pointer to 0x00 Hex
  Wire.endTransmission();                        //End xmit to I2C.  Send requested data.
  Wire.requestFrom(DS1307, 7);                   //Get 7 bytes from RTC buffer
  second = BCD2DEC(Wire.read() & 0x7f);          //Seconds.  Remove hi order bit
  minute = BCD2DEC(Wire.read());                 //Minutes
  hour = BCD2DEC(Wire.read() & 0x3f);            //Hour.  Remove 2 hi order bits
  DoW = BCD2DEC(Wire.read());                    //Day of week
  Date = BCD2DEC(Wire.read());                   //Date
  month = BCD2DEC(Wire.read());                  //Month
  year = BCD2DEC(Wire.read());                   //Year
  timeString = 2000+year;                        //Build Date-Time data to write to SD
  if (month<10){timeString = timeString + '0';}  //Pad leading 0 if needed
  timeString = timeString + month;               //Month (1-12)  
  if(Date<10){timeString = timeString + '0';}    //Pad leading 0 if needed
  timeString = timeString + Date;                //Date (1-30)
  timeString = timeString + DoWList[DoW];        //1Sun-7Sat (0=null)
  if (hour<10){timeString = timeString + '0';}   //Pad leading 0 if needed
  timeString = timeString + hour + ':';          //HH (0-24)
  if (minute<10){timeString = timeString + '0';} //Pad leading 0 if needed
  timeString = timeString + minute + ':';        //MM (0-60)
  if (second<10){timeString = timeString + '0';} //Pad leading 0 if needed
  timeString = timeString + second;              //SS (0-60)
}
```

Comment: I don’t know what “the well known String problems” are, but there is no `String` type in standard C++.

Comment: Character arrays do not have concatenation operators. If you want to store a number into a string you must _convert it_ to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at the std-library type `std::string` yet (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)?

Even though used as "string" in C, `char[]` is not really a string; it is an array and the variable holding that (in your case `timeString`) is more treated like a pointer, than a container (that's what distinguishes C and C++ from other languages). If you want to use a container with overloads for arithmetic operators (`+`), then you need to use the convenience classes provided by the standard library (or, if you're very bold, you can reimplement them yourself - but why should one reimplement the square wheel?).

For serialization usually the stream from the standard library are used (`std::cout` and `std::cin` are global stream variables). Have a look at `std::stringstream` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream), I guess that could be of interest for you.

Comment: It looks like "Concatenating strings" might work. Will give it a try.
 std::string str3 = str1 + " " + str2;